# confused with Google Maps JavaScript API usage

Tags: javascript, api

We have autocomplete functionality on our website. We used Google services to implement this functionality. What we do is:

- get predictions from google as user types some letters with

```html
var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
service.getPlacePredictions(...);
```

- then when user selects one of the suggested locations we make another call to get location coordinates with

```html
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'placeId': suggestion.placeid }, function (results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results[0]) {
      ...
    }
  }
});
```

on our google developers console we enabled "Google Maps JavaScript API" and "Google Maps Geocoding API". This works as expected localy on our machines. We also see the usage/quota per API on developers console. But on production used APIs are not as expected. It never consumes "Google Maps Geocoding API" and it doesn't work if we don't enable "Google Places API Web Service". We see all usage/quota under "Google Places API Web Service". If it was behaving the same on both development and production environment then no problems, but does any one have an idea why the consumed quotas are on different APIs?